# Spring Batch HibernateItemWriter "Not an entity" eventhough EntityScan is set (no xml configuration)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

i have some trouble setting up an HibernateItemWriter in my Spring-Batch program.

This is what my HibernateConfig.class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setConfigLocation(context.getResource("mypath/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

and my related hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info">info</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.jdbcUrl">jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=dbname</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.username">no</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.password">no</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.poolName">Mssql-Pool</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">10000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">300000</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and these are the annotations i use in the "Application" class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EntityScan(basePackages = "mypackagespath")
@Import(DataSourcesConfig.class) 
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer ...
```

This is what my HibernateWriter looks Like:

```
@Bean
public HibernateItemWriter<MyEntity> writer() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = hibernatecfg.getSessionFactory();
    HibernateItemWriter<MyEntity> myWriter = new HibernateItemWriter<>();
    myWriter.setSessionFactory(localSessionFactoryBean.getObject());
    myWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
    return myWriter;
}
```

My domain class has the @Entity and @Table annotations and the EntityScan package path is fine. But somehow Hibernate does not find the annotated Entity and gives me the following error:

```
exitStatus=exitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity [class <packages.MyEntity.class>]
```

I do not want to create a persistence.xml thats why i want to use the @EntityScan Annotation:

Answer (score 0):

You may refer below link, may be it will help,

https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/

@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.springbootdev.domain.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.springbootdev.domain.repository"})

Comment: Thank you for the link. The provided text says that the Annotations are required if the JpaRepo and the Entity are not in subpackages from the Main Package. In my case both Classes are in Subpackages from Main...

Comment: If you have all sub-packages under Main package directly or indirectly then you can use @EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: i use the @SpringBootApplication which provides the features of 
    Configuration
    EnableAutoConfiguration
    ComponentScan

So EnableAutoConfiguration should already be active.